# Can you create time series graphs from log-based metrics?

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, monitoring, metrics

I have two GCP (Google Cloud Platform) related monitoring questions:

1. Is it possible to create a timeseries from a [log-based metric](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/). I understand that you can make up a `distribution` or `counter` metric from logs, however I cant seem to create sensible timeseries-like graphs with the metric explorer. Does that mean that I am limited to creating a timeseries metric by [creating custom metric](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/distribution-metrics), i.e. via the stackdriver API.
2. If the only way is to use the stackdriver API to create timeseries graphs, what is the common approach to get around the [one data point per minute limitation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#writing-ts) when publishing frequently changing data?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: You are not limited to `one data point per minute` if you use [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This might be the solution for the long term. Stackdriver seems very limiting in my opinion.